# Finding every longest endgame for each material configuration

Tags: endgame, tablebases

I can find statistics on the number of moves until checkmate in the [Syzygy endgame table](https://syzygy-tables.info/endgames) for each material configuration. Let's say I am interested in ["KQQvK" endgames](https://syzygy-tables.info/?fen=8/8/8/1k6/8/3K4/3Q4/3Q4_b_-_-_0_1). [The statistics](https://syzygy-tables.info/stats/KQQvK.json) show that there are exactly 40 positions in which white can force mate in no less then 6 half-moves. Here is one such example given by their [endgames.pgn file.](https://syzygy-tables.info/endgames.pgn)

```
[FEN "8/8/8/1k6/8/3K4/3Q4/3Q4 b - - 0 1"]
```

Of course, I could mirror this position in every possible way, but this will not cover all 40 positions that require the maximum amount of moves. How is it possible to generate each position?

Comment: I'm not sure there is an easy way to do this. You could of course generate your own tablebases and keep track of this, but I think at least the syzygy files themselves don't give you easy access to that information.

Answer (score 1):

[Kirill Kryukov's website](http://kirill-kryukov.com/chess/longest-checkmates/longest-checkmates.shtml) is perhaps the best starting point. Here, all of the longest endgames for material configurations are given if for positions with 6 pieces or less and without a 5+1 piece count. For the moves, you could make a script to run each position through [Shredder]([https://www.shredderchess.com/online/endgame-database.html}](https://www.shredderchess.com/online/endgame-database.html%7D) and record the best move sequence.

For reference, here is the entire list copied down and sorted by length, which the site [has as an option.](http://kirill-kryukov.com/chess/longest-checkmates/longest-checkmates-sorted-by-length.shtml)

KRNKNN  262 6k1/5n2/8/8/8/5n2/1RK5/1N6 w - - 0 1

KRPKNN  253 8/1P1k4/2R5/n7/1n6/K7/8/8 w - - 0 1
KRRPKQ  253 q7/7k/8/6R1/8/8/2P2R2/K7 w - - 0 1
KRNKNP  252 8/8/8/8/7k/8/1R2p2N/1K1n4 w - - 0 1

KRBKNN  238 8/8/8/8/2n2k2/2n5/5BR1/1K6 w - - 0 1

KRBKNP  229 8/8/2R5/3B4/k7/3np3/K7/8 w - - 0 1

KRRPKP  218 8/7k/8/8/PR3R2/8/p7/3K4 w - - 0 1
KRPPKQ  216 8/k1P5/8/8/1R5P/8/K7/7q w - - 0 1
KRPPKP  211 8/k1P5/8/8/1R5P/8/7p/3K4 w - - 0 1

KRNKBN  209 NbR5/8/n7/8/8/8/8/2K2k2 w - - 0 1
KRBKPP  208 8/8/8/8/7B/4k3/K1p1pR2/8 w - - 0 1
KRPKBN  204 8/1P6/8/n7/2K5/1b1R4/8/6k1 w - - 0 1

KRPKNP  198 4n3/6P1/5k2/8/8/8/1p1K4/R7 w - - 0 1
KRNKBP  194 8/8/7R/3kN3/1K6/8/5p1b/8 w - - 0 1

KRNKPP  188 8/2K5/R6N/8/8/2p5/5p2/3k4 w - - 0 1
KQPPKQ  182 8/4k3/8/Q7/8/7P/P7/q1K5 w - - 0 1
KBBPKR  180 2B5/4Br2/K1k5/8/8/8/6P1/8 w - - 0 1

KPPPKQ  178 6k1/P7/8/8/3q4/7P/P1K5/8 w - - 0 1
KQNKRR  174 3r2r1/8/k7/8/8/8/3K4/1Q4N1 w - - 0 1
KPPPKP  171 8/7k/2P5/1K6/8/5p1P/P7/8 w - - 0 1

KRPKBP  166 8/3R2P1/7k/8/8/8/5p2/K5b1 w - - 0 1
KQPKRR  165 8/3P2k1/8/3K4/8/8/r4r2/5Q2 w - - 0 1

KBPPKQ  158 8/5B1P/8/8/3k4/7P/4q3/1K6 w - - 0 1
KQBPKQ  158 8/5B1Q/8/8/3k4/6qP/8/1K6 w - - 0 1
KQPKRB  155 8/1kb5/8/8/3r4/8/4P3/2K1Q3 w - - 0 1
KRNKBB  152 8/7R/4b3/8/4k3/5b2/8/K6N w - - 0 1
KBPPKP  151 8/8/8/7B/4p2P/K2k3P/8/8 w - - 0 1
KQPKQP  151 8/3q4/2p4P/8/7Q/1k6/8/K7 w - - 0 1

KBPPKR  149 8/4P3/1r6/8/5B2/8/P7/K2k4 w - - 0 1
KBNPKR  141 3k4/8/r7/7N/8/8/K4BP1/8 w - - 0 1
KPPKPP  141 8/8/2p4P/5P2/1k6/4p3/K7/8 w - - 0 1
KQPKPP  141 2k5/2p5/1K6/7P/7Q/8/6p1/8 w - - 0 1

KRPKBB  136 8/8/3k2P1/1b6/8/8/K1R5/3b4 w - - 0 1
KQNPKQ  133 K3q3/3N4/8/8/8/k3P3/4Q3/8 w - - 0 1
KNPPKP  131 8/8/4NP2/8/1K6/3P4/p6k/8 w - - 0 1
KBBKNP  131 K7/8/8/k7/Bp6/7n/7B/8 w - - 0 1
KNPPKQ  130 8/5P2/4N3/8/8/K2P4/7k/6q1 w - - 0 1

KQPKQB  128 4b3/8/8/8/6Q1/k1K1P3/5q2/8 w - - 0 1
KQPKQN  128 4n1Q1/8/8/8/2K5/4P3/k4q2/8 w - - 0 1
KBNKNP  128 k7/6p1/8/1n1K4/8/5N2/8/4B3 w - - 0 1
KPPKP   127 8/8/8/8/1p2P3/4P3/1k6/3K4 w - - 0 1
KRBPKQ  127 8/7q/1R1P4/8/8/7B/3K4/k7 w - - 0 1
KQRPKQ  127 8/4R3/8/8/8/K1q1P1Q1/8/k7 w - - 0 1
KQPKQR  126 4r3/8/8/8/8/4P3/1k1K1Q2/1q6 w - - 0 1
KQPKRP  126 8/8/8/1K6/2Q5/1r2P3/1k4p1/8 w - - 0 1
KQPKBP  126 4b3/8/8/Q7/8/1k2P3/1p6/2K5 w - - 0 1
KQPKNP  125 4n3/8/8/8/8/3QP3/kp6/2K5 w - - 0 1
KPPKQ   124 8/4P3/7q/8/8/8/k1K1P3/8 w - - 0 1
KQPKQ   124 4Q3/8/7q/8/8/8/k3P3/2K5 w - - 0 1
KBNKPP  124 k1K5/7p/6NB/8/8/5p2/8/8 w - - 0 1
KQPKQQ  124 2Q5/8/7q/8/8/4P3/3q4/k1K5 w - - 0 1
KQRPKP  124 5Q1R/8/8/8/8/8/1p2P3/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KRNPKQ  123 7q/8/1NK5/4P3/1R6/8/8/k7 w - - 0 1
KQPPKP  123 8/8/8/Q7/8/8/1Pp1P3/1k1K4 w - - 0 1
KRBNKP  122 R3B3/N7/8/8/8/3K4/6p1/1k6 w - - 0 1
KQQPKQ  122 k1K1q3/8/8/8/8/8/6P1/5Q1Q w - - 0 1
KRNPKP  121 2N5/8/3K4/3P4/4k3/6R1/5p2/8 w - - 0 1
KRBNKQ  121 R3B3/8/8/1N6/8/3K4/8/1k4q1 w - - 0 1
KRBPKP  120 8/8/4P3/8/R2K4/B7/3p4/7k w - - 0 1

KRPKQR  118 6R1/5P2/8/2k1r2q/8/K7/8/8 w - - 0 1
KQRKQR  117 4q3/7R/8/4r2Q/8/4k3/8/2K5 w - - 0 1
KRPKRP  116 8/7P/1K5R/8/1r1k4/8/4p3/8 w - - 0 1
KNNKP   115 1N6/8/p7/8/8/8/2k1N3/K7 w - - 0 1
KQNPKP  115 8/8/8/8/5Q2/4P3/1pN5/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KNNPKP  114 1N6/8/p7/8/2Pk4/8/8/1K4N1 w - - 0 1
KBNPKQ  113 3N4/3P4/2K5/8/1k1q4/8/7B/8 w - - 0 1
KQRKRP  113 8/1K6/3Q3R/1r6/k7/8/4p3/8 w - - 0 1
KRBKBN  112 B7/8/8/4b3/8/1R6/3kn3/K7 w - - 0 1
KQBPKP  112 3B4/8/8/8/8/4P1Q1/1p6/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KBNPKN  111 5n2/8/8/2KN4/8/7k/B6P/8 w - - 0 1
KQPKRN  110 8/2n5/8/8/1K3r2/Q7/2kP4/8 w - - 0 1

KNNNKP  109 8/p7/8/8/8/4NN2/K3k3/7N w - - 0 1
KBNNKN  109 4k2N/3N4/2n5/8/8/3K4/2B5/8 w - - 0 1
KQQPKP  109 8/8/8/Q7/6Q1/8/1p1P4/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KBBNKN  108 8/8/8/8/8/8/1B4NB/2Kn3k w - - 0 1
KBNNKP  108 8/8/8/p3kB2/1K3N2/8/8/7N w - - 0 1
KRRNKQ  108 5R1N/8/5R2/8/7k/q7/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KBNKN   107 8/8/8/8/8/8/1n5B/2K1N2k w - - 0 1
KQBKRR  107 3r4/6Q1/5B2/8/8/5k2/2Kr4/8 w - - 0 1
KBNKQN  107 8/8/8/8/8/6B1/1n6/1Kq1N2k w - - 0 1
KBNKRN  107 8/8/8/8/8/6B1/1n6/1Kr1N2k w - - 0 1
KBNKBN  107 8/8/8/8/8/6B1/1n6/1Kb1N2k w - - 0 1
KBNKNN  107 8/8/8/8/8/6B1/1n6/1Kn1N2k w - - 0 1
KRBNKN  107 8/8/8/8/2R5/n5B1/8/1K2N2k w - - 0 1
KRNNKP  107 RN6/Nk6/p7/8/8/8/K7/8 w - - 0 1
KQBNKN  107 8/8/8/8/2Q5/n5B1/8/1K2N2k w - - 0 1
KBBKNN  106 4n3/8/8/B7/8/3K4/8/n1kB4 w - - 0 1
KBPKRR  106 8/r3P3/8/8/8/1r6/B7/2K3k1 w - - 0 1
KQPKP   105 8/8/8/8/3P2Q1/8/1p6/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KBPPKN  105 8/7P/6k1/5n2/3K3B/8/7P/8 w - - 0 1
KBBPKN  105 8/6n1/B3P3/8/2K5/8/7k/3B4 w - - 0 1
KQBKRP  105 8/Q7/8/K4rp1/5B2/8/6k1/8 w - - 0 1
KBNKQP  105 8/8/3q4/2K5/1p6/8/k7/5B1N w - - 0 1
KBNKRP  105 8/8/3r4/2K5/1p6/8/k7/5B1N w - - 0 1
KBNKBP  105 8/8/3b4/2K5/1p6/8/k7/5B1N w - - 0 1
KBNKP   104 8/8/3K4/8/8/1p6/k7/5B1N w - - 0 1
KQKRP   104 8/Q7/K7/5r2/5p2/8/6k1/8 w - - 0 1
KRPKQP  104 3R4/2P5/2K5/4q3/6k1/4p3/8/8 w - - 0 1
KBBKPP  104 B7/B7/8/5p2/8/2p5/1K1k4/8 w - - 0 1
KBPKRP  104 K7/8/4B2P/8/5p2/4r3/2k5/8 w - - 0 1
KPKRP   103 K7/7P/4r3/8/5p2/8/2k5/8 w - - 0 1
KBNPKP  103 8/8/3K4/8/8/1P6/1pk5/5B1N w - - 0 1
KBBNKP  103 8/8/3K4/8/8/kB1B4/1p6/N7 w - - 0 1
KQRKQP  103 2QR4/8/2K5/4q3/8/4p3/5k2/8 w - - 0 1
KQNKRP  103 8/K4r2/8/5N2/5p2/8/6k1/Q7 w - - 0 1
KRPKPP  103 8/2K3R1/8/3p4/8/4pP2/4k3/8 w - - 0 1
KBPKQN  102 3q4/2P5/7B/6n1/3K4/8/k7/8 w - - 0 1
KBPKRN  102 3r4/2P5/7B/6n1/3K4/8/k7/8 w - - 0 1
KRBKBP  101 8/8/8/8/8/K7/1pkb4/3R3B w - - 0 1
KBPKN   100 1n6/3P4/8/8/1K6/7B/8/k7 w - - 0 1

KBBPKQ  98  8/P1qB3k/4B3/8/8/8/K7/8 w - - 0 1
KNPKN   97  k7/3P4/2n5/K7/8/8/3N4/8 w - - 0 1
KQQKRP  97  8/8/1pk5/K7/8/8/Qr6/4Q3 w - - 0 1
KQRKPP  97  8/8/4QR2/8/8/4p3/1pk5/K7 w - - 0 1
KNPPKR  97  8/k1PN1r2/8/8/8/1P6/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KBBPKP  97  8/8/K6P/6B1/8/4B3/1p4k1/8 w - - 0 1
KNNNKB  96  6bN/8/8/8/8/1N6/2k5/K6N w - - 0 1
KQBBKQ  96  8/6k1/4B3/8/6B1/3q4/8/1K5Q w - - 0 1
KRPPKR  95  8/8/8/8/1k6/3r2P1/7P/K6R w - - 0 1

KNPPKN  93  7N/8/8/5k2/8/1P6/1P6/1K4n1 w - - 0 1
KNNPKN  92  N2n4/1P6/k7/4N3/3K4/8/8/8 w - - 0 1
KRBKBB  92  7k/4R2B/8/8/8/3K2bb/8/8 w - - 0 1
KQNNKP  92  8/8/8/1p6/QK6/5N2/8/4N2k w - - 0 1
KRBPKN  91  8/8/8/2K5/k7/3n1P1B/8/4R3 w - - 0 1
KQBPKN  91  8/8/8/2K5/k7/3n1P1B/8/4Q3 w - - 0 1
KBBKBN  90  8/8/k7/8/8/4B3/6n1/1BK4b w - - 0 1
KNNNKN  90  7N/N7/1k6/8/8/8/2K1n3/1N6 w - - 0 1
KRRBKQ  90  8/7B/8/k7/8/8/1R6/1RK1q3 w - - 0 1
KRPKQB  90  bK6/6P1/8/2q5/8/1k6/8/R7 w - - 0 1

KQRKQB  89  R7/8/1k6/8/3q4/8/8/bK4Q1 w - - 0 1
KRRKRN  89  r7/8/8/6n1/8/1k6/3RR3/2K5 w - - 0 1
KRRNKP  89  7N/8/8/2R5/8/R7/4p3/3K1k2 w - - 0 1
KNPPKB  88  8/8/N1b5/8/k7/8/2P1P3/K7 w - - 0 1
KRNPKN  88  1k6/R7/2nP4/K5N1/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1
KPPPKN  87  8/5P2/2n1k3/8/3K4/1P6/1P6/8 w - - 0 1
KBBNKR  85  N7/1r4B1/8/8/8/7B/8/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KRNPKR  85  8/7N/8/8/8/2k5/4r2P/K2R4 w - - 0 1

KQPKBB  84  8/8/7P/8/4k3/3b4/3b4/1KQ5 w - - 0 1
KQBNKQ  84  7q/8/8/8/5B1N/2K4k/5Q2/8 w - - 0 1
KPKBB   83  8/8/7P/8/4k3/b7/8/1K3b2 w - - 0 1
KQRKQN  83  8/4nq2/8/k7/8/8/4Q3/3K2R1 w - - 0 1
KBPPKB  82  1k6/8/8/1P4B1/8/1K6/4P3/7b w - - 0 1
KQNKBB  82  8/8/8/3k4/4bb2/8/8/QKN5 w - - 0 1
KQKBB   81  8/1Q6/8/8/2bb4/8/3k4/K7 w - - 0 1
KQBKBB  81  8/1Q6/8/8/2bb4/3B4/3k4/K7 w - - 0 1
KQQKBB  81  8/8/3Q4/8/4k3/1b2b3/8/3KQ3 w - - 0 1
KQRKBB  81  5R2/8/7b/8/4k3/3b4/8/QK6 w - - 0 1
KQRKBP  81  2K5/4k3/8/8/5R2/7b/2p4Q/8 w - - 0 1
KNNPKB  80  1b6/8/2k5/3N4/8/6N1/3P4/K7 w - - 0 1
KQRKQQ  80  q3Q3/8/5q2/8/8/8/3k4/1K5R w - - 0 1
KBBKQN  80  8/8/8/5q2/1n6/B2k4/B7/2K5 w - - 0 1
KBBKRN  80  8/8/8/8/5n1B/3k3B/1r6/2K5 w - - 0 1
KQPKNN  80  8/2n5/8/K7/1Pn5/8/2k5/7Q w - - 0 1
KRRKRP  80  8/8/8/K7/8/kpR5/2R5/7r w - - 0 1
KRPKQQ  80  8/P7/5q2/8/8/5k2/KR6/7q w - - 0 1

KRPKQN  79  n7/1P6/7k/8/6R1/8/q7/2K5 w - - 0 1
KQBBKP  79  8/8/8/8/8/4Q3/1pkB3B/K7 w - - 0 1
KBBKN   78  7B/6n1/8/6k1/6B1/8/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KPPPKB  78  8/4k1P1/8/3K4/8/8/2bP3P/8 w - - 0 1
KBBBKN  78  8/8/8/8/8/1kn5/1B2B3/3K3B w - - 0 1
KRBBKN  78  8/8/8/8/8/1nk5/3RB3/K1B5 w - - 0 1
KRBKRP  77  k2r4/8/8/Kp6/8/8/4B3/7R w - - 0 1
KQRNKQ  77  8/6NR/8/8/8/2q5/5k2/K6Q w - - 0 1
KRBPKR  76  8/8/1B6/1k6/R7/2r5/6P1/K7 w - - 0 1
KRPKRB  76  8/2R5/8/8/2br1k2/8/1PK5/8 w - - 0 1
KRBBKP  76  8/8/8/8/8/8/4p1RB/3K1k1B w - - 0 1
KQBBKN  76  8/1B6/3Q4/1n6/3K4/8/2kB4/8 w - - 0 1
KBBKRP  76  8/8/8/2k5/6B1/1p2r3/8/3KB3 w - - 0 1
KBBBKR  75  6B1/8/8/6r1/8/7k/7B/K5B1 w - - 0 1
KNNPKQ  75  3K4/6P1/q3k3/8/8/8/8/2N2N2 w - - 0 1
KRRPKR  75  1R6/k7/8/8/6R1/8/6P1/1K2r3 w - - 0 1
KRPKRR  75  8/8/3r3k/8/8/8/rP1R4/3K4 w - - 0 1
KRPKRN  75  8/8/3n3k/8/8/8/rP1R4/3K4 w - - 0 1
KBBKBP  75  8/8/8/5k2/B5b1/1p2B3/3K4/8 w - - 0 1
KBBKQP  75  8/8/8/5k2/B5q1/1p2B3/3K4/8 w - - 0 1
KQRPKR  75  2k5/8/8/6R1/8/8/6P1/r1K2Q2 w - - 0 1

KBBKP   74  8/8/8/8/4k1B1/1p2B3/2K5/8 w - - 0 1
KRPKR   74  k7/8/8/8/8/4R3/6P1/1K5r w - - 0 1
KPKNN   74  8/8/7P/8/4n3/1k6/8/3K3n w - - 0 1
KBBBKP  74  8/8/5B2/8/8/8/4pkB1/3K3B w - - 0 1
KQNNKQ  74  2N2N2/8/8/8/8/q4k2/8/3K2Q1 w - - 0 1
KRPKB   73  8/8/R7/8/8/1k1P4/6b1/K7 w - - 0 1
KRRBKP  73  8/8/8/7R/8/8/1p6/K1k3BR w - - 0 1
KQBNKP  73  Q3B3/N7/8/8/8/8/1p6/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KQKNN   72  8/8/8/8/4n2Q/3k4/8/3K3n w - - 0 1
KQBKRB  72  8/b7/6Q1/8/8/5B2/3k4/K1r5 w - - 0 1
KQQKQB  71  8/8/1k6/2q5/6Q1/b7/8/2K4Q w - - 0 1
KQRKRB  71  8/R7/6Q1/8/3b4/8/1K1k4/5r2 w - - 0 1
KQNKRB  71  5Q2/8/8/r4b2/8/5k2/5N2/1K6 w - - 0 1
KRBPKB  71  7b/8/8/8/8/5k2/1K1P4/RB6 w - - 0 1
KRNPKB  71  8/8/8/8/4b3/1k2PN2/8/1KR5 w - - 0 1
KBPKRB  71  8/5P2/8/Bb1r4/8/8/4k3/1K6 w - - 0 1
KPKRB   70  8/4P3/b7/r7/8/8/8/1K4k1 w - - 0 1
KQKRB   70  8/4Q3/b7/r7/8/8/8/K5k1 w - - 0 1
KPPPKR  70  8/2P5/2P1r3/k7/8/2K5/5P2/8 w - - 0 1
KRPPKB  70  7b/8/8/8/1R6/3P4/2kP4/K7 w - - 0 1
KRRPKB  70  7b/8/8/8/8/3R4/2kP4/KR6 w - - 0 1
KBNPKB  70  8/8/8/8/7b/8/1K1k1P2/N5B1 w - - 0 1
KQQKRB  70  5Q2/8/8/Q7/8/r2b4/4k3/1K6 w - - 0 1
KRBBKR  70  1k6/R7/8/B6B/8/8/3K4/r7 w - - 0 1

KQKRN   69  8/5Q2/8/n7/8/4k3/8/3K2r1 w - - 0 1
KQBKNN  69  8/7Q/8/B3n1k1/8/1n6/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KQQKNN  69  8/7Q/8/Q3n1k1/8/1n6/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KQQKQR  69  Q5Q1/1r6/2k4q/8/8/8/8/1K6 w - - 0 1
KQRKNN  69  8/7Q/8/R3n1k1/8/1n6/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KQRKNP  69  8/5R2/8/K7/8/1n6/2p4Q/1k6 w - - 0 1
KQBKRN  69  8/2B1r3/6Q1/2k5/8/5n2/3K4/8 w - - 0 1
KQNKRN  69  8/8/8/Q7/6N1/6rk/n7/2K5 w - - 0 1
KRRBKR  69  8/1B6/8/5R2/7R/8/8/K1r3k1 w - - 0 1
KRRRKQ  69  1R4R1/8/8/7R/q7/8/5k2/3K4 w - - 0 1
KRPKQ   68  8/P1k5/8/8/8/1q6/R7/K7 w - - 0 1
KPKRN   68  1n6/1K1P4/8/8/8/8/4r3/1k6 w - - 0 1
KQNKNN  68  8/8/3Q4/8/2N1k3/n7/3n4/1K6 w - - 0 1
KRBKRN  68  8/7n/8/4R3/8/k2KB3/8/3r4 w - - 0 1
KRBNKR  68  8/8/8/4R3/5r1B/8/Nk1K4/8 w - - 0 1
KQQRKQ  68  8/8/8/q7/3Q4/6k1/8/KR5Q w - - 0 1
KQRBKR  68  3Q4/k7/4R3/8/8/8/6B1/rK6 w - - 0 1
KBPKQP  68  8/7p/8/8/8/q7/K6P/2k4B w - - 0 1
KBPKP   67  8/7p/8/8/8/1B6/K6P/2k5 w - - 0 1
KQRKQ   67  8/8/8/8/q7/6k1/8/KR5Q w - - 0 1
KRKNP   67  2K4k/7p/8/8/8/8/3R4/n7 w - - 0 1
KQRKRN  67  8/8/8/Q7/5R2/4k3/n7/2K3r1 w - - 0 1
KRRKRB  67  3b4/r7/8/8/4R3/8/k7/2K3R1 w - - 0 1
KRBKRR  67  2r5/8/B7/2R5/7r/3K4/8/5k2 w - - 0 1
KQRRKQ  67  8/8/8/q7/1R6/6k1/8/KR5Q w - - 0 1
KQRBKQ  67  8/7R/8/1B6/8/q7/5k2/K6Q w - - 0 1
KQRPKB  67  8/8/4Q3/3b4/8/8/K1kP4/R7 w - - 0 1
KNNPKR  66  8/8/4PN2/K7/8/7N/1r6/1k6 w - - 0 1
KQQKRN  66  8/8/8/8/1n3k2/1Q6/Q7/1K4r1 w - - 0 1
KQNKNP  66  8/8/8/2k5/2nN4/5Q2/1p1K4/8 w - - 0 1
KRRKNP  66  8/7k/8/6Rp/3K4/5n2/R7/8 w - - 0 1
KRBKR   65  8/3B4/8/1R6/5r2/8/3K4/5k2 w - - 0 1
KRBKQR  65  8/4B3/8/6R1/r7/3q4/2K5/k7 w - - 0 1
KRBKRB  65  2R5/8/8/B7/7b/3r4/8/k1K5 w - - 0 1
KQNKQP  65  8/2K1k3/2p5/1N6/8/8/1Q6/7q w - - 0 1

KQBKNP  63  8/6Q1/8/3n4/1K3B2/8/1pk5/8 w - - 0 1
KQBKQP  63  q7/p7/8/7k/QB6/8/8/3K4 w - - 0 1
KQNKPP  63  8/4k3/2p1N3/1K6/8/8/4Q2p/8 w - - 0 1
KPPKBN  61  8/8/8/P6P/K1k5/8/4b3/4n3 w - - 0 1
KQNPKN  61  8/K7/2n5/4Q3/8/8/P7/5k1N w - - 0 1
KQQKQN  60  7n/8/8/8/1k6/8/7Q/q1K3Q1 w - - 0 1
KQQKNP  60  8/8/8/8/7Q/2k5/2pnQ3/1K6 w - - 0 1
KQQKQP  60  QQ6/8/8/8/1K4q1/8/4p3/2k5 w - - 0 1

KPKNP   58  8/3K4/8/6p1/P7/8/6n1/7k w - - 0 1
KQBKQB  58  7q/1B5b/8/8/7Q/3k4/8/3K4 w - - 0 1
KQBKBP  58  5B2/8/1K6/8/2k5/8/7p/Q5b1 w - - 0 1
KBPKQB  58  6bq/3P4/1k6/8/K7/8/8/5B2 w - - 0 1
KNPKP   57  N7/8/K7/8/4p3/8/6P1/k7 w - - 0 1
KQRKRR  57  R7/7Q/8/8/8/8/8/2rKr1k1 w - - 0 1
KRPKP   56  R7/P7/8/K7/8/8/pk6/8 w - - 0 1
KBNNKR  56  4B3/8/5r2/8/3N1N2/8/3K4/7k w - - 0 1
KQPKBN  56  1K6/3n4/2k3P1/4Q3/8/8/5b2/8 w - - 0 1
KQRBKP  56  Q7/R7/8/1B6/8/8/1p6/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KPKBN   55  8/8/3P4/8/8/2k5/8/1K2n2b w - - 0 1
KQKNP   55  8/7Q/8/K7/8/8/3p4/n1k5 w - - 0 1

KPPKR   54  3K4/8/8/4P3/8/2r5/5P2/2k5 w - - 0 1
KRPKN   54  8/5n2/8/8/8/7k/7P/3K3R w - - 0 1
KBBPKB  54  b7/8/6B1/3K4/8/8/2P5/Bk6 w - - 0 1
KRPPKN  54  8/4R3/8/K1k1P3/2n5/4P3/8/8 w - - 0 1
KRRPKN  54  8/RK6/3n4/3k4/2R5/4P3/8/8 w - - 0 1
KQPPKR  54  Kr6/8/8/2P5/8/3P4/5Q2/7k w - - 0 1
KQKBN   53  8/8/8/8/3b4/1Q6/3kn3/K7 w - - 0 1
KQRKBN  53  8/8/8/1R6/3b4/1Q6/3kn3/K7 w - - 0 1
KQBKBN  53  8/8/8/8/3b4/1Q6/3kn3/K2B4 w - - 0 1
KQNKQR  53  1r6/8/8/7k/8/5N2/2K1Q3/q7 w - - 0 1
KQNKBN  53  8/8/8/2N5/3b4/1Q6/3kn3/K7 w - - 0 1
KBNNKB  53  5N2/8/3b4/8/8/8/8/K1Bk3N w - - 0 1
KBBNKB  53  8/8/B7/2N4B/3k4/8/8/1K1b4 w - - 0 1
KRBBKQ  53  4R1B1/1q6/5B2/k7/8/3K4/8/8 w - - 0 1
KRNKRN  52  7n/8/5R2/8/3r4/8/8/k2K3N w - - 0 1
KRNKRP  52  k7/8/1K4p1/8/r7/8/3N4/3R4 w - - 0 1
KBPKB   51  8/8/6B1/8/2P5/8/2K5/k4b2 w - - 0 1
KPKBP   51  3K4/8/1P6/8/6p1/8/4b3/7k w - - 0 1
KQQKBP  51  8/Q7/8/8/4b3/1k6/5p2/QK6 w - - 0 1
KQNKBP  51  2K5/8/8/8/6b1/1Q6/4N1pk/8 w - - 0 1
KQRPKN  51  8/7R/8/8/4Q3/6kP/3n4/1K6 w - - 0 1
KQBPKB  51  8/8/2B5/8/b7/1KP5/2Q5/k7 w - - 0 1
KPPKN   50  3n4/5P2/8/8/3K2P1/8/k7/8 w - - 0 1
KPKRR   50  3K4/4P3/1r2k3/8/8/8/8/7r w - - 0 1
KQKBP   50  3K4/8/8/8/8/1Q6/4b1pk/8 w - - 0 1
KQQKQQ  50  8/7k/8/1q1q4/8/8/8/K4QQ1 w - - 0 1

KQKRR   49  4r3/8/5Q2/8/5r2/1k6/8/1K6 w - - 0 1
KQBKQR  49  7q/4B2r/8/8/8/8/1Q6/3K3k w - - 0 1
KQRNKP  49  4Q2R/8/8/8/8/8/1p6/K1k3N1 w - - 0 1
KBPKQR  49  2q5/kP6/2K5/3r4/8/8/B7/8 w - - 0 1
KQQKBN  48  8/8/8/8/8/1kn5/4Q1Q1/1K3b2 w - - 0 1
KQQKRR  48  4Q3/8/7Q/8/8/2rk4/8/2K1r3 w - - 0 1
KRRKPP  48  8/8/k7/p7/1K6/3R4/2p1R3/8 w - - 0 1
KRRRKP  46  7R/8/5R2/8/8/5R2/1pk5/K7 w - - 0 1
KQBKPP  46  8/8/8/3K4/8/8/p2Q1B1p/5k2 w - - 0 1
KQQNKR  46  7N/8/8/8/8/6Q1/5Q2/K1r4k w - - 0 1
KQQPKR  46  k7/P5Q1/Q7/8/8/8/r7/K7 w - - 0 1
KBPKR   45  8/r1k5/5P2/3K4/B7/8/8/8 w - - 0 1
KRRKBB  45  8/8/1b6/3b4/4R3/8/5k2/K6R w - - 0 1
KRRNKR  45  7k/5R2/5N2/8/8/6R1/8/K4r2 w - - 0 1
KRRKQP  45  5k1q/R2R4/3p4/8/8/8/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KQQNKQ  45  4Q3/8/2N5/8/k7/8/7Q/q1K5 w - - 0 1
KQRRKP  45  8/R7/8/3Q4/5R2/2k5/1p6/K7 w - - 0 1
KQNPKR  45  K7/r7/3P4/8/8/3N2Q1/8/7k w - - 0 1

KNPKR   44  1N6/8/8/PK6/3r4/3k4/8/8 w - - 0 1
KQNKQB  44  6Q1/b7/8/3N4/8/8/k2K4/7q w - - 0 1
KRRKBN  44  4n1b1/8/8/8/2R5/8/4R3/1K1k4 w - - 0 1
KQRNKR  44  8/8/8/8/1R6/1Q6/2Kr1N2/k7 w - - 0 1
KQBNKR  44  8/8/8/4B3/8/5N2/7Q/K1r2k2 w - - 0 1
KQPPKN  44  8/8/8/8/8/3KP3/Q5P1/2n1k3 w - - 0 1
KPKR    43  8/5k2/2PK4/5r2/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1
KPPKB   43  8/6P1/7k/8/6P1/1K6/8/1b6 w - - 0 1
KNPKB   43  8/8/8/8/2K5/b7/1k5P/2N5 w - - 0 1
KPKPP   43  8/8/7P/3K4/5p2/4p3/8/7k w - - 0 1
KPKQR   43  8/2P2k2/3q4/2K2r2/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1
KQNKQN  43  6q1/n7/8/Q7/8/2K5/8/3Nk3 w - - 0 1
KRRKQN  43  7k/1n6/8/8/8/q7/2KR4/4R3 w - - 0 1
KRRKNN  43  8/2R5/8/8/2n4k/3n4/2R5/2K5 w - - 0 1
KRRKBP  43  8/5R2/8/8/k2K4/1R3b2/3p4/8 w - - 0 1
KQBPKR  43  8/8/2P2k2/8/8/r1K4Q/7B/8 w - - 0 1
KQBKQN  42  Q7/8/7q/8/2B5/3K4/n7/2k5 w - - 0 1
KQNKQQ  42  6q1/8/8/Q7/8/2qK4/8/1N1k4 w - - 0 1
KRBKQN  42  8/8/8/5n2/B7/3R4/2K3k1/7q w - - 0 1
KRNKQN  42  8/8/8/n7/2R4q/8/3k4/1K2N3 w - - 0 1
KRNNKR  42  8/8/8/6N1/8/1r6/6RN/K6k w - - 0 1
KQQBKR  42  8/8/8/8/8/6Q1/5Q2/K1r1B2k w - - 0 1
KQNPKB  42  8/8/8/8/1N6/4b3/7P/k1K3Q1 w - - 0 1
KNPKQ   41  8/4P3/8/N1K5/k7/8/7q/8 w - - 0 1
KQNKQ   41  6q1/8/8/Q7/8/2K5/8/3Nk3 w - - 0 1
KRKNN   41  8/5R2/8/8/k7/4n3/3K1n2/8 w - - 0 1
KRKBN   41  8/5R2/8/8/k7/4b3/3K1n2/8 w - - 0 1
KRKRN   41  8/5R2/8/8/k7/4r3/3K1n2/8 w - - 0 1
KRKQN   41  8/5R2/8/8/k7/4q3/3K1n2/8 w - - 0 1
KQKPP   41  8/8/8/2K5/5p2/8/1Q2pk2/8 w - - 0 1
KQRRKR  41  7k/1R6/8/5QR1/8/r7/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KRKN    40  8/2R5/8/8/7k/3K4/8/4n3 w - - 0 1
KRBKN   40  8/2R5/8/8/7k/4n3/6B1/3K4 w - - 0 1
KRRKN   40  8/2R5/8/8/7k/4n3/6R1/3K4 w - - 0 1
KQBKR   40  8/7B/8/7k/5Q2/8/8/Kr6 w - - 0 1
KQRKP   40  8/Q7/R7/8/8/8/1p6/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KQRKN   40  8/2R5/8/8/7k/4n3/6Q1/3K4 w - - 0 1
KRKPP   40  2K5/8/3pR3/5p2/7k/8/8/8 w - - 0 1
KRRKRR  40  1R6/rR1r4/k7/8/8/8/2K5/8 w - - 0 1
KBNKQB  40  6B1/7q/8/8/6N1/3k4/8/1Kb5 w - - 0 1
KBNKRB  40  6B1/7r/8/8/6N1/3k4/8/1Kb5 w - - 0 1
KBNKBB  40  6B1/7b/8/8/6N1/3k4/8/1Kb5 w - - 0 1
KQQKPP  40  6Q1/8/8/8/8/8/1pkp2Q1/K7 w - - 0 1
KQQBKQ  40  6Q1/8/5B2/8/8/8/3k4/QK1q4 w - - 0 1
KQBBKR  40  8/7B/8/7k/5Q2/8/1B6/Kr6 w - - 0 1

KBNKB   39  8/7B/8/4N3/8/8/3k4/K1b5 w - - 0 1
KRKBP   39  8/6bp/8/8/k1K5/8/8/2R5 w - - 0 1
KBNNKQ  39  8/8/1B6/8/2q3N1/2N5/8/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KBBNKQ  39  8/q7/8/8/8/2k3BB/1N6/1K6 w - - 0 1
KRBNKB  39  8/8/8/R7/Nb6/8/3K4/k5B1 w - - 0 1
KQBNKB  39  8/Q7/3B4/8/3K4/8/4Nb2/1k6 w - - 0 1
KQNNKR  39  k7/2Q5/8/8/5N2/3r4/8/1N1K4 w - - 0 1
KQNKR   38  k7/2Q5/8/8/8/8/3r4/1N1K4 w - - 0 1
KQKQR   38  8/8/6q1/8/8/8/2krQ3/K7 w - - 0 1
KRBKQP  38  1R6/8/B7/3q4/8/2K5/1p6/7k w - - 0 1
KRNKN   37  8/8/8/8/RN6/1k6/8/3K1n2 w - - 0 1
KRNKR   37  8/8/8/8/N2K4/R7/8/2k1r3 w - - 0 1
KQPKR   37  8/8/P7/3k4/r7/8/8/KQ6 w - - 0 1
KRNKQR  37  8/8/8/8/N2K4/8/R7/q1k1r3 w - - 0 1
KRNKRR  37  8/8/8/8/N2K4/8/R7/r1k1r3 w - - 0 1
KRNKRB  37  8/8/8/8/r7/8/3K4/kNRb4 w - - 0 1
KQQQKR  37  8/8/8/1Q6/2Q5/k7/3r2Q1/3K4 w - - 0 1
KQQRKR  37  8/8/8/1Q6/2Q5/k7/3r2R1/3K4 w - - 0 1
KQQRKP  37  7R/8/8/1Q6/7Q/2k5/3p4/2K5 w - - 0 1
KQQNKP  37  8/Q7/2Q5/2N5/8/8/1p6/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KBNKR   36  8/8/8/2r5/3B4/8/3N4/K3k3 w - - 0 1
KBNKQ   36  8/8/8/2q5/3B4/8/3N4/K3k3 w - - 0 1
KBNKQQ  36  8/8/8/8/3N4/1q6/7B/K1kq4 w - - 0 1
KBNKQR  36  8/8/8/8/3N4/1r6/7B/K1kq4 w - - 0 1
KBNKRR  36  8/8/8/8/3N4/1r6/7B/K1kr4 w - - 0 1
KQKR    35  8/8/8/8/2r5/8/2k5/K6Q w - - 0 1
KQQKR   35  8/8/8/6Q1/5Q2/7k/r7/K7 w - - 0 1
KBPKQ   35  8/3P1q2/2k5/6B1/8/8/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KBPKQQ  35  8/P7/2k5/8/4q3/5q2/8/KB6 w - - 0 1

KBNNK   34  8/8/8/6N1/6kB/6N1/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KQRKR   34  8/8/8/8/3RQ3/2k5/8/K4r2 w - - 0 1
KPKQP   34  k1q5/2K5/7p/8/8/8/6P1/8 w - - 0 1
KQBKQQ  34  8/8/7q/8/8/qQ1K4/B7/2k5 w - - 0 1
KRRKQB  34  8/R7/8/8/8/8/2RK1k2/5bq1 w - - 0 1
KRNNKN  34  8/8/8/2n5/8/6kN/3K2NR/8 w - - 0 1
KRRBKN  34  8/6Bk/4R3/2R5/5n2/3K4/8/8 w - - 0 1
KQRBKN  34  8/6Bk/4Q3/2R5/5n2/3K4/8/8 w - - 0 1
KQPPKB  34  8/8/8/8/1k6/2b3P1/1K4P1/Q7 w - - 0 1
KBNK    33  8/8/7N/8/8/8/8/K1k1B3 w - - 0 1
KPKP    33  2K5/k7/7p/8/8/8/6P1/8 w - - 0 1
KPPPK   33  K7/8/8/8/2k3P1/6P1/6P1/8 w - - 0 1
KBNPK   33  K1k5/2P5/8/7B/8/8/8/N7 w - - 0 1
KBBNK   33  8/8/8/8/8/B7/5Bk1/K6N w - - 0 1
KRRKP   33  8/8/6R1/8/8/8/4p1R1/3K1k2 w - - 0 1
KQBKQ   33  7q/8/8/k7/8/7B/3K4/4Q3 w - - 0 1
KRKRP   33  7R/8/8/k7/8/r7/Kp6/8 w - - 0 1
KRKQP   33  7R/8/8/k7/8/q7/Kp6/8 w - - 0 1
KRRKQR  33  8/k7/8/8/1q6/5rR1/8/1RK5 w - - 0 1
KRNNKQ  33  3q4/N6R/8/N7/8/k7/2K5/8 w - - 0 1
KRRNKN  33  8/8/8/RN3R2/1k6/4n3/2K5/8 w - - 0 1
KRRRKR  33  8/8/4R1R1/5k2/7R/8/r7/K7 w - - 0 1
KQRNKN  33  8/8/8/RN3Q2/1k6/4n3/2K5/8 w - - 0 1
KPPK    32  8/8/8/8/8/2k3P1/6P1/K7 w - - 0 1
KNPPK   32  7N/K5k1/8/8/8/6P1/6P1/8 w - - 0 1
KQBKP   32  8/Q7/2K3k1/8/8/8/7p/2B5 w - - 0 1
KRBKQB  32  8/8/8/8/2R5/B7/5k2/3K1bq1 w - - 0 1
KRNKQB  32  8/8/8/8/4b3/8/2RN3k/3K1q2 w - - 0 1
KRRRKN  32  8/R7/8/3R4/1R6/8/2n5/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KQQRKN  32  8/R7/8/3Q4/1Q6/8/2n5/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KQRRKN  32  8/R7/8/3R4/1Q6/8/2n5/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KBPK    31  8/3P4/KBk5/8/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1
KRNKB   31  8/8/8/8/4b3/8/2R5/3K1Nk1 w - - 0 1
KRRKR   31  k7/6R1/8/8/1R6/2r5/8/2K5 w - - 0 1
KRKBB   31  8/8/8/b1R5/8/3K4/8/1k4b1 w - - 0 1
KQQQKQ  31  1Q6/Q7/8/8/3q4/8/2k5/K4Q2 w - - 0 1
KRNKQP  31  8/8/8/4R3/8/3p2q1/3k3N/K7 w - - 0 1
KBBPK   30  4B3/6P1/7k/8/8/8/K7/1B6 w - - 0 1
KRBKB   30  8/8/8/8/8/3R4/6k1/3K1bB1 w - - 0 1
KQPKN   30  8/Q7/2n5/1k6/3K4/8/7P/8 w - - 0 1
KQNKP   30  8/8/2K4N/8/8/5Q2/p1k5/8 w - - 0 1
KQQKQ   30  1Q6/Q7/8/8/8/8/2k5/K4q2 w - - 0 1
KRKRB   30  8/8/8/8/Rr6/3K4/8/1k4b1 w - - 0 1
KRKQB   30  8/8/8/8/Rq6/3K4/8/1k4b1 w - - 0 1
KRNNKB  30  8/8/8/8/8/3K4/5kNR/1b4N1 w - - 0 1
KQQBKP  30  3Q4/Q7/8/8/2B5/8/1p6/K1k5 w - - 0 1

KPKN    29  8/8/8/k7/8/n7/K5P1/8 w - - 0 1
KPKB    29  8/8/8/k7/8/b7/K5P1/8 w - - 0 1
KPKQ    29  8/8/8/k7/8/q7/K5P1/8 w - - 0 1
KRKB    29  8/8/8/8/8/2R5/8/3K1bk1 w - - 0 1
KRBNK   29  8/8/8/8/8/8/6kB/K5NR w - - 0 1
KRNKP   29  8/8/8/4R3/8/2k3N1/3p4/K7 w - - 0 1
KRRKB   29  8/7R/1R6/8/4b3/8/2K5/5k2 w - - 0 1
KRRKQ   29  k2q4/7R/8/8/8/8/8/2K3R1 w - - 0 1
KQRKB   29  8/8/8/5b2/8/R2K4/6k1/1Q6 w - - 0 1
KPKQN   29  8/n7/8/1k1q4/3K3P/8/8/8 w - - 0 1
KQKQP   29  2Qq4/2K5/8/8/8/8/4p3/2k5 w - - 0 1
KRRKQQ  29  8/8/8/8/8/RRq5/7q/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KRBBKB  29  8/b7/8/8/3K4/8/BBk5/R7 w - - 0 1
KPK 28  8/8/8/1k6/8/8/K5P1/8 w - - 0 1
KQKP    28  3Q4/3K4/8/8/8/3k4/3p4/8 w - - 0 1
KNNPK   28  N1N5/8/8/8/8/4k2P/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KRBKP   28  8/8/8/8/8/1R1K4/kB1p4/8 w - - 0 1
KQPKB   28  8/8/k7/8/1Q6/2K5/6P1/4b3 w - - 0 1
KRRNKB  28  5R2/6b1/8/8/8/R7/6k1/K6N w - - 0 1
KRRBKB  28  7b/8/3R4/4RB2/5k2/8/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KNPK    27  8/7N/8/8/8/5k2/7P/K7 w - - 0 1
KQRBKB  27  8/8/8/8/8/2kb4/Q7/RKB5 w - - 0 1
KQRNKB  27  8/8/8/4b3/5Q2/3kN3/7R/K7 w - - 0 1
KRKP    26  8/8/K7/3p4/8/3k4/4R3/8 w - - 0 1
KBBBKB  26  8/8/7b/8/8/5k2/2B5/1B1KB3 w - - 0 1
KQQQKP  26  k7/5Q2/8/4Q3/8/8/1p1Q4/2K5 w - - 0 1
KBPPK   25  B7/1K6/8/8/8/3k3P/7P/8 w - - 0 1
KNNNKR  25  8/8/8/6r1/8/8/5N2/KNk3N1 w - - 0 1

KPKQB   24  qk6/6P1/6b1/1K6/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1
KQKQN   24  3q4/2n5/8/8/8/8/6Q1/k2K4 w - - 0 1
KQKQB   24  8/2b5/8/8/8/8/k2K1Q2/q7 w - - 0 1
KBBBKQ  24  8/8/8/8/6B1/5B2/5k1q/B2K4 w - - 0 1
KNNNKQ  24  8/8/8/8/2NN3q/8/8/K1k3N1 w - - 0 1
KQQPKN  24  8/8/8/P2Q4/1Q6/8/2n5/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KBBKR   23  4r3/8/8/8/8/8/8/k1K3BB w - - 0 1
KBBKBB  23  8/8/8/8/8/4k3/7B/1Kb3bB w - - 0 1
KBBKQR  23  4r3/8/8/8/3q4/8/8/k1K3BB w - - 0 1
KBBKQB  23  8/8/8/8/8/4k3/7B/1Kb3qB w - - 0 1
KBBKRR  23  4r3/8/8/8/3r4/8/8/k1K3BB w - - 0 1
KBBKRB  23  8/8/8/8/8/4k3/7B/1Kb3rB w - - 0 1
KQBBKB  23  8/8/4B1b1/8/8/k2K4/8/1Q2B3 w - - 0 1
KBBKB   22  8/8/8/2B5/8/8/3k4/K1b4B w - - 0 1
KQQKP   22  8/8/8/3Q4/7Q/2k5/1p6/K7 w - - 0 1
KQKN    21  8/8/8/8/8/2k5/2n5/KQ6 w - - 0 1
KNNNK   21  8/8/8/8/8/8/N4k2/KN4N1 w - - 0 1
KBBKQ   21  8/8/8/1q4B1/8/3k4/6B1/K7 w - - 0 1
KRBKQ   21  1q6/8/8/8/8/8/8/k1KR2B1 w - - 0 1
KQNKN   21  8/8/8/8/3N4/2k5/1n2Q3/3K4 w - - 0 1
KQBKN   21  8/8/8/8/8/2kB4/1n2Q3/3K4 w - - 0 1
KRBKQQ  21  1q6/8/8/8/3B4/2R1q3/8/k1K5 w - - 0 1
KBBKQQ  21  8/3q4/8/8/BB6/8/3q4/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KRNKQ   20  8/8/8/8/R7/6q1/5N2/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KRKRR   20  8/8/R2r4/8/8/3k4/1r6/K7 w - - 0 1
KRKQR   20  8/8/R2q4/8/8/3k4/1r6/K7 w - - 0 1
KRNKQQ  20  8/8/8/8/R1q5/6q1/5N2/K1k5 w - - 0 1

KBBK    19  8/8/8/8/7B/8/3k4/K2B4 w - - 0 1
KRKR    19  8/8/8/8/8/1R6/6r1/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KRKQ    19  8/8/8/8/8/1R6/6q1/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KQQKN   19  8/8/8/4k3/2Q5/n7/3Q4/1K6 w - - 0 1
KRKQQ   19  8/8/8/8/8/8/1R4q1/Kqk5 w - - 0 1
KRRRKB  18  8/2R5/8/4b3/5R2/4k3/7R/K7 w - - 0 1
KQRRKB  18  8/8/8/8/6b1/3k4/8/2RKQR2 w - - 0 1
KQKB    17  8/6Q1/8/4b3/3k4/8/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KRNPK   17  6k1/6NR/7P/8/8/8/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KQNKB   17  8/8/8/4b3/8/8/N1k5/K4Q2 w - - 0 1
KQBKB   17  8/8/8/4k3/3b4/8/5Q2/K3B3 w - - 0 1
KNKPP   17  8/p1p5/8/8/8/8/8/kNK5 w - - 0 1
KQNNKB  17  8/1N6/8/7N/3bk3/8/1Q6/K7 w - - 0 1
KRK 16  8/8/8/8/8/2k5/1R6/K7 w - - 0 1
KRPK    16  8/8/1R6/2kP4/8/8/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KRNK    16  8/8/8/8/3N4/3k4/2R5/K7 w - - 0 1
KRBK    16  8/8/8/8/3B4/3k4/2R5/K7 w - - 0 1
KBBBK   16  8/8/8/3B4/3B4/3k4/3B4/3K4 w - - 0 1
KRBPK   16  8/8/8/8/BR6/kP6/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KQQBKN  16  8/8/8/8/2kB3Q/5Q2/3n4/1K6 w - - 0 1
KQQPKB  16  8/8/8/4b3/5Q2/1P1k4/Q7/K7 w - - 0 1
KRPPK   15  8/8/8/8/2kP4/8/1R1P4/K7 w - - 0 1
KRNNK   15  8/5NR1/5kN1/8/8/8/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KQQKB   15  8/8/8/8/8/3k1b2/8/2QKQ3 w - - 0 1

KRRPK   14  8/K7/8/8/5k2/4RPR1/8/8 w - - 0 1
KQQRKB  14  8/8/8/8/5R2/2k1b3/8/1QKQ4 w - - 0 1
KQQBKB  14  3Q4/8/8/8/8/2b5/Q1B5/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KQQNKB  14  3Q4/8/8/8/8/2b5/Q1N5/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KQKQ    13  8/8/8/8/8/8/8/qk1K2Q1 w - - 0 1
KPKQQ   13  qk4q1/5P2/8/1K6/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1
KQKQQ   13  8/8/8/8/8/8/3q4/qk1K2Q1 w - - 0 1
KQQNKN  13  N6Q/8/8/8/4k3/1n6/3Q4/K7 w - - 0 1
KQNNKN  13  8/N7/8/8/8/2k5/2nN4/KQ6 w - - 0 1
KRBBK   12  8/8/8/8/3B4/3k4/2RB4/K7 w - - 0 1
KQK 10  8/8/8/5k2/8/8/1Q6/K7 w - - 0 1
KQPK    10  8/8/8/3k4/8/4P3/8/K1Q5 w - - 0 1
KRRNK   10  8/8/6R1/6Nk/6R1/8/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KRRBK   10  8/6R1/6Bk/6R1/8/8/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KNNKBN  10  7n/8/8/4b3/8/3N4/k7/1NK5 w - - 0 1

KQNK    9   8/8/5k2/8/8/8/8/KN4Q1 w - - 0 1
KQPPK   9   8/8/8/8/8/3kP3/3P4/K1Q5 w - - 0 1
KQNPK   9   NQ6/8/8/8/4k3/8/1P6/K7 w - - 0 1
KQBPK   9   8/8/8/8/8/8/k1PK4/2QB4 w - - 0 1
KBKNP   9   1B6/8/8/8/8/8/p7/k2K2n1 w - - 0 1
KNNKNN  9   7n/8/8/8/2N5/8/4N3/knK5 w - - 0 1
KQBK    8   8/5B2/5k2/8/8/8/8/KQ6 w - - 0 1
KQNNK   8   N7/N7/8/8/8/5k2/8/K1Q5 w - - 0 1
KNKBP   8   8/8/8/b7/8/p7/3N4/k1K5 w - - 0 1
KNKRP   8   8/8/8/8/3N4/p7/3r4/k1K5 w - - 0 1
KNKQP   8   8/8/8/q7/8/p7/3N4/k1K5 w - - 0 1
KQQQKN  8   Q7/8/Q7/8/1Q6/8/2n5/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KRRK    7   8/8/8/8/8/3k4/2R5/KR6 w - - 0 1
KNKP    7   8/8/8/8/p7/8/N7/k1K5 w - - 0 1
KQBNK   7   8/8/8/8/4N3/3kB3/Q7/K7 w - - 0 1
KQRPK   7   6Q1/8/8/8/8/8/6Pk/K5R1 w - - 0 1
KNNKN   7   7n/8/8/8/8/8/2NK4/1kN5 w - - 0 1
KNKNP   7   8/8/8/8/pn6/8/N7/k1K5 w - - 0 1
KNNKRN  7   7n/8/8/4r3/8/8/3N4/kNK5 w - - 0 1
KNNKQN  7   7n/8/8/8/2N5/1q6/8/k1NK4 w - - 0 1
KQRK    6   8/8/8/8/3k4/2R5/8/K6Q w - - 0 1
KQBBK   6   8/8/8/8/8/1B6/Q1B1k3/K7 w - - 0 1
KRRRK   5   8/8/8/8/4k3/5R2/R7/RK6 w - - 0 1
KQRNK   5   Q7/N7/8/8/8/8/3k4/K1R5 w - - 0 1
KQRBK   5   1Q6/8/8/8/3B4/3k4/2R5/K7 w - - 0 1
KNNKRB  5   8/8/8/8/1N6/1r6/1b6/1k1K1N2 w - - 0 1
KQQQKB  5   5Q2/8/8/8/3b4/5Q2/Q7/K1k5 w - - 0 1

KQQK    4   1Q6/Q7/8/8/8/5k2/8/K7 w - - 0 1
KQRRK   4   5Q2/5R2/8/8/8/3k4/4R3/K7 w - - 0 1
KQQPK   4   3Q4/3Q4/8/8/8/3P4/8/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KQQNK   4   1Q6/2N5/1Q6/8/8/8/4k3/K7 w - - 0 1
KQQBK   4   3Q3Q/8/8/8/3B4/8/4k3/K7 w - - 0 1
KQQRK   4   8/8/8/8/4k3/8/1K6/QR1Q4 w - - 0 1
KNNKB   4   8/8/8/8/1N6/8/1b6/k1NK4 w - - 0 1
KBKPP   4   8/8/8/1p6/8/8/p7/k2KB3 w - - 0 1
KNNKQB  4   8/8/8/8/1N6/1q6/1b6/k1NK4 w - - 0 1
KNNKBB  4   8/8/8/8/8/3N4/k7/bNK3b1 w - - 0 1
KQQQK   3   8/8/1Q6/Q7/1Q6/8/8/K4k2 w - - 0 1
KNNKR   3   8/8/8/8/3N4/r7/8/k1K1N3 w - - 0 1
KBKBP   3   8/8/8/8/8/8/p7/kbBK4 w - - 0 1
KNNKQR  3   8/8/8/8/3N4/r7/2q5/k1K1N3 w - - 0 1
KNNKRR  3   8/8/8/8/3N4/r7/2r5/k1K1N3 w - - 0 1
KBKBN   2   8/8/8/8/2n5/8/b7/k1K1B3 w - - 0 1
KBKBB   2   8/8/8/8/8/8/b7/k1K1b1B1 w - - 0 1
KBKRP   2   8/8/8/8/8/8/p2r3B/k1K5 w - - 0 1
KBKRB   2   8/8/8/8/8/8/b2r3B/k1K5 w - - 0 1
KBKQP   2   8/8/8/8/8/8/p3q3/k1K1B3 w - - 0 1
KBKQB   2   8/8/8/8/8/8/b3q3/k1K1B3 w - - 0 1

KNNK    1   8/8/8/8/8/4N3/3N4/K1k5 w - - 0 1
KNKN    1   8/8/8/8/8/8/n1K5/k1N5 w - - 0 1
KNKB    1   8/8/8/8/8/8/b7/k1K1N3 w - - 0 1
KNKR    1   8/8/8/8/8/8/r2N4/k1K5 w - - 0 1
KBKP    1   8/8/8/8/8/8/p7/k1K1B3 w - - 0 1
KBKN    1   8/8/8/8/8/8/n1K5/k1B5 w - - 0 1
KBKB    1   8/8/8/8/8/8/b7/k1K1B3 w - - 0 1
KNNKQ   1   8/8/8/8/8/4N3/3N4/K1k1q3 w - - 0 1
KNKNN   1   8/8/8/8/n7/kn6/8/NK6 w - - 0 1
KNKBN   1   8/8/8/8/b7/kn6/8/NK6 w - - 0 1
KNKBB   1   8/8/8/8/8/N7/b7/k1K1b3 w - - 0 1
KNKRN   1   8/8/8/8/8/8/2rN4/K1kn4 w - - 0 1
KNKRB   1   8/8/8/8/8/8/2rN4/K1kb4 w - - 0 1
KNKRR   1   8/8/8/8/8/8/2rN4/K1kr4 w - - 0 1
KNKQN   1   8/8/8/8/q7/kn6/8/NK6 w - - 0 1
KNKQB   1   8/8/8/8/8/8/b1q5/k1K1N3 w - - 0 1
KNKQR   1   8/8/8/8/8/8/2rN4/K1kq4 w - - 0 1
KBKNN   1   8/8/8/8/8/8/n1K5/knB5 w - - 0 1
KBKRN   1   8/8/8/8/8/8/n1K5/k1Br4 w - - 0 1
KBKQN   1   8/8/8/8/8/8/n1K5/k1B1q3 w - - 0 1
KNNKQQ  1   8/8/8/8/8/4N3/3N4/K1k1qq2 w - - 0 1

KNK -   -
KBK -   -
KNKQ    -   -
KBKR    -   -
KBKQ    -   -
KNKQQ   -   -
KBKRR   -   -
KBKQR   -   -
KBKQQ   -   -

Comment: The [endgames.pgn file](https://syzygy-tables.info/endgames.pgn) mentioned in my question is a strictly better source when it comes to finding a longest endgame. I am interested in all (!) longest endgames rather than just one.

Comment: @WilfredMontoya What do you mean "one"? I have listed literally all of them for up to 6 pieces (minus 5 to 1).

Comment: Take KRNvKNN for example. You provided exactly one endgame (6k1/5n2/8/8/8/5n2/1RK5/1N6 w - - 0 1), which is indeed a longest endgame for the given piece configuration. But your list has to be incomplete since we can mirror this position and get another longest endgame, for example (1k6/2n5/8/8/8/2n5/5KR1/6N1 w - - 0 1). For any given piece configuration I'd like to know all longest endgames.

Comment: @WilfredMontoya That seems rather arbitrary, but alrighty. Good luck with your endeavor.